# Use one DatePicker to choose date for end and start time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a booking create view, where the user can choose a start and end time with date and time. However I want to have one field to choose date and two fields as start and end time (only time, no date), so the date selected in the field is the date for both end and start DateTime.

Right now I have three DateTime values and the HTML tags DataType.Date and DateTime.Time, so it in the user view this already 'works'. But it sets the date of the start and end time to Date.Now, so I have to create a new DateTime value for start and end with the date from the date field. This works, but is there are simpler, better way to do this? Or do I have to change the way I initialize my values with DateTime.MinValue/MaxValue?

My booking class:

```
private DateTime day; 
private DateTime start = DateTime.MinValue;
private DateTime end = DateTime.MaxValue;

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Required]
public DateTime day //+get set methods

[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[Required]
public DateTime start //+get set methods

[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[Required]
public DateTime end //+get set methods
```

Part of my Create method in the controller:

```
public IActionResult Create(Booking b)
{   
 DateTime temp = b.end;
 newRequest.end = DateTime.MaxValue; //necessariy so it won't throw an exception, because start time has to be before end time
 b.start = new DateTime(b.day.Year, b.day.Month, b.day.Day, b.start.Hour, b.start.Minute, b.start.Second);
 b.end = new DateTime(b.day.Year, b.day.Month, b.day.Day, temp.Hour, temp.Minute, temp.Second);
}
```

Comment: For your view model, shouldn't you use `DateTime?` ?

Comment: I have considered this, but then the booking distribution algorithm would be a lot more complicated, because right now you can sort it in one list by the date time and otherwise you need multiple sorted lists for each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is going to end up in your variables but it shouldn't matter.. let's assume that day has the correct date and maybe some incorrect or irrelevant time, and start and end have some incorrect or irrelevant date, maybe today or 01/01/0000, and a correct time:

```
DateTime chosenStart =
  day.Date //in case it has some stray time component 
  + (start - start.Date); //make a time span and add to day
```

- You can add a DateTime and a TimeSpan together using +
- You can generate a TimeSpan from two datetimes by subtracting the earlier one from the later one

As your start DateTime is a time but represented as a datetime we can turn it into a time span by asking how long since its own midnight:

```
2000-01-01_12:34 minus 2000-01-01_00:00 is a time span of 12:34
```

It doesn't matter what the date is, by subtracting the midnight datetime from the with-time datetime we get the time as a timespan..

.. which can be added to another midnight datetime to generate a date and time in that day

If you're dead certain that day will only ever be a datetime with a midnight date you can skip the .Date call on it

```
var x = day + (start - start.Date);
```

Now just be careful that your time zoning logic is all good!

Comment: thanks for your help, that looks a lot cleaner than my version. Day does indeed have an irrelevant time value..

Comment: I should add that you can actually make a timespan from dates by subtracting any from any, earlier or later.. it's just that if you do `earlier - later` it is negative, which you don't want in this case